# setting content offest , hide the table

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I am using `setContentOffset` method to scroll the table to last cell.But table gets invisible automatically.

```
 self.tblViewStatus.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: CGFloat.max), animated: false)
```

is there any other way to scroll the table to last cell ?

Answer (score 0):

use `- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: I used that, some top cell gets invisible and in some case table does not scroll to last.